# Docker Context - Не подключается к удалённому хосту

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

1. Добавил контекст:

```sh
docker context create remote --docker "host=ssh://user@example.com"
```

2. Проверил подключение по SSH (*подключается*):

```sh
ssh user@example.com
```

3. Пробую посмотреть контейнеры на удалённом хосте:

```sh
docker --context remote ps
```

Получаю:

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at http://docker.example.com. Is the docker daemon running?

В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том, что на удалённом хосте `user` не был в группе `docker`. Я его добавил и всё заработало:

```sh
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Если не заработало, то возможно стоит перезагрузить удалённый хост, но у меня заработало и без перезагрузки.

---

Почему в сообщении об ошибке указан хост `http://docker.example.com` — это просто общий плейсхолдер.

---

Источник: https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/15142/35216